# Weird Bug in XCode StoryBoard after upgrading to iOS SDK 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Last night I updated `XCode` and the `iOS SDK`.

It looks like it messed up the `UINavbar` on the storyboard, here is a pic:

[image]

It shows two titles overlapping, if I delete the title , then there is still another one in the background, Im not able to remove that second one.

The strange part is it magically disapear, if I run the app.

```
XCODE version --> Version 5.1 (5B130a)
iOS SDK---------> Version 7.1
```

Comment: I've seen some confusion because there are two different places the title can be set.  First in the view controller properties itself.  Second in the properties of the view controller's navigation item.  Check and make sure that you don't have it both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked again and there was an extra `navigation bar`, its weird that It shows only after I upgraded, I think something happen with that `view` because I embedded it into a `navigation controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a new property for the uiviewcontrollers named "exteded edges" you must uncheck this in the interface builder inside the uiviewcontroller preferences. Or by inserting this code in your view did load. This will tell the controller not to draw the view under the navigation bar.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]){
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
```